# AWS Gateway Lambda Cookies

Tags: java, cookies, aws-lambda, amazon-gateway

I am having a problem finding a way of how to access the cookie that is sent to my AWS Lambda. I have an API Gateway with lambda proxy integration (POST) to my Lambda.

From my client java program I am making an http POST request with body(Json) and with an `HttpCookie` in the `CookieStore` inside the `CookieManager`. This request goes to my Lambda where the body is printed to the console. This works fine but unfortunately I don't know how to access the cookie that was sent with the POST request. I am using Java 8 and `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` to get the body.

Can anybody please provide me some assistance on how to get the cookie from `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` event or maybe another workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are sent in the `Headers` within the `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` object — `request.Headers.Cookie`.

The important thing is to parse the cookies since values of `Headers` are always `String`.

Here's how you can access it and create a key-value `HashMap` so that it's easier to use.

```java
String cookiesStr = request.getHeaders().getOrDefault("Cookie", "");
String[] cookiesArr = cookiesStr.split(";");

Map<String, String> cookiesMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] cookieSplits;

for(String cookie : cookiesArr) {
    cookieSplits = cookie.trim().split("=");
    cookiesMap.put(cookieSplits[0], cookieSplits[1]);
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
logger.log("CookiesMap:\n" + gson.toJson(cookiesMap));
```

The output of that will look something like this:

```json
CookiesMap:
{
    "TestCookie1": "value1",
    "TestCookie2": "value2"
}
```